# Is there any way to specify the class of objects of a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

Im having the following problem:

I've made a NSMutableArray "array" that is going to contain objects of a class named "Class". At the start that array should be empty and it must be filled during the program's execution.

As I never actually told the compiler that my NSMutableArray will be holding elements of the class Class, when I try to write the appropriate methods the compiler wont let me do it.

This is my first experience on Objective-C and iPhone development. I used to code in C/C++ where I declared my arrays in the following way:

```
Class array[NUMBEROFELEMENTS];
```

Is there any way to do this in Objective-C?

Thanks!

Comment: even if it is for illustration only, you may want to choose a name other than "Class" since "Class" is an existing objc typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truth is that is doesn't matter to the NSMutableArray what type of object it is.  NSMutableArray simply stores pointers to all the objects they contain, or reference.

The trick is when you pull the object back out of the array you need to create a new pointer based on the appropriate type:

```
MyObject *myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you can use the object however you like:

```
[myObject doThatThingWithThisValue:10];
```

Or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Objective-C Cocoa are objects (as well as other collections, sets, dictionaries). Arrays can contain references to objects of any type, so the type for the array is *simply* `NSArray`, `NSMutableArray`, etc...

Since they are objects, you can send them messages to manipulate their content.

I suggest you take a look at Apple's excellent [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html), which explain the rudiments of collections.

Here is a quick example :

```
// two objects of different types
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:10];
NSString *s = @"foo";

// alloc/init a new mutable array
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
// add an object
[a addObject:n];
[a addObject:s];
// array a now contains a NSNumber and a NSString
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can still have C-style arrays in Objective-C.

However, the characteristics of Objective-C (some people will call it strength, other will call it weakness) is that it has dynamic typing of objects and dynamic dispatch.

It has `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` which are not specialized for the certain class. It can store objects of non-compatible classes.

You can use the following idiom: `[obj isMemberOfClass: [Class type]]` to make sure an array element is of the desired type and then cast to `Class*`.

You can also use for-each loop (aka Fast Enumeration):

```
NSMutableArray* array = //... initialize your array
for (Class* elm in array) {
     elm.your_property = 10;
}
```